# How to optimize the procedure method?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

My procedure query take 19.546s you can see at the bottom of the below snapshot. And you can see there total data is 60370 item. The procedure query take much time, 19.546s is so long.

[image]

So, is there a method to optimize my procedure? This is my procedure:

```
BEGIN
    declare icount int default 0;
  declare exit handler for SQLEXCEPTION set out_a=1;
  select count(*) into icount from P01 where P0101=in_a;
  if icount=0 THEN
    set out_a=1;
    set out_b=0;
    set out_c='';
    set out_d='';
  ELSE
    set out_a=0;
    select P0106,P0107,P0108 into out_b,out_c,out_d from P01 where P0101=in_a;

    if in_b=1 then
      select P0202,P0203,P0204,P0205 from P02 where P0201=in_a and P0204=out_b+1 order by P0202;
    ELSE
      select P0202,P0203,P0204,P0205 from P02 where P0201=in_a and P0204>=out_b+1 order by P0202;
    end if;
  end if;

END
```

Is there a way to cut down the time of the procedure spend?

---

**EDIT**

If I query my table `p02` it will spend 20+s:

```
select * from p02;
```

[image]

So, where maybe the issue ?

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on those queries, find where you're missing indexes.

Comment: @miken32 I update my question, you can see that, query the table also takes long time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create indexes on table `P02`:

   ```
   create index i_P0201 on P02(P0201);
   create index i_P0202 on P02(P0202);
   create index i_P0204 on P02(P0204);

   create index i_P0101 on P01(P0101);
   ```
2. Avoid arithmetic operations on query: `P0204>=out_b+1`, just use calculated values like:

   ```
   set @out_b_plus1 = out_b+1;
   ```

   And use that value in query:

   ```
   `P0204 >= @out_b_plus1`
   ```

Maybe the optimization will be a few seconds less because your table have large data.

Comment: but `select * from p02` also is 20+ s. what issue caused the long time?

Comment: The 20s is caused by the amount of data transferred to client

Comment: but 60k items data will spend 20+s transferred to client?